# Why didn't anyone design or create JVM like middleware for other language( not only C or CPP)?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, programming-languages, jvm, interpreter

As we know that we have JVM for converting bytecode into machine code which is provided to it by Java Compiler. We all know that JVM is platform dependent. One question which comes to mind is why didn't anyone create JVM like application for other languages to achieve platform independence? If JVM is to achieve Platform independence then I think each and every language can be platform independent and there is just a need to write some compiler and JVM like application which could have helped other languages become platform independent.

Please don't consider only CPP or C.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: They have. They're just not well-maintained anymore.

Comment: Why would anyone down vote this question?

Comment: @hexafraction Please let me know about some of them.

Comment: i guess this question got downvoted and will be closed soon, because it is primarily opinion based or off topic - decide for yourself what's worse

Comment: May be people do so because they don't have actual answers? Thanks and regards.

Comment: http://mobile.slashdot.org/story/13/07/14/2348226/an-interesting-look-at-the-performance-of-javascript-on-mobile-devices specially the second half about garbage collection and VMs

Comment: Please check the question now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that C++ is far to unspecified and machine dependent to have a portable usefull bytecode format.

How would you have a c++ bytecode and vm when you don't even know the size of an int, long og pointer?

Also it would be far to slow, and there is not really much of a benefit to do it.

------ ADDED ---------

And even if you could do it, what would the benefit be. All c++ programs still depend on on the operation system for most of its services, so even if you for example had a portable format for C++, a windows program would still only be able to run on Intel/Amd x86 chips, because that is the only chip supported by Windows.

Yes I know about Windows RT(The arm version), but that version of Windows removed most of the methods normal desktop c++ programs depend on, which is also why you can't just (re)compile a windows program for Windows RT.

Comment: You are just telling that it is platform dependent. I am just asking Why is that so? reason is Each and every language would be machine dependent if there's no middleware like JVM to talk to both Machine Code and Byte Code.

Comment: Speed. C and C++ is designed to maximize performance, and be usefull for any kind of cpu. It was/is a design choice.

Comment: I'm not convinced. The fact that C/C++ are unspecified is actually helpful when defining a VM: *you* get to decide how big ints and longs are and all the other "implementation defined" behavior. As to it being slow, the VM could use JIT just like the JVM, so the performance could be near-native.

Comment: An example: How would you be create a platform independent way to optimize for all the different simd extensions such as mmx,sse*, altivec and so on.

Comment: Yes, but what happens if the vm defines sizes different from what the cpu support? It will kill performance. It can be done, but you will just end up with something like java or .net, and they already exists. The joke is always, that Java is what you get when you try to make c++ safe and portable.

Comment: @MTilsted : Sir FYI JAVA and MS .NET did not come prior to C and CPP. Thanks and regards.

Comment: I know. Java is suns implementation of a safe and portable c++

Comment: @MTilsted : So is the reason sir. I just want to know that why did't existing CPP got a JVM like application to help it overcome issues. Why the name "Java" even generated?